# How to aggregate count of unique values of categorical variables in R

Tags: r, unique, distinct-values, summarization

Suppose I have a data set `data`:

```
x1 <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")
x2 <- c("a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","a1","b1","b1","b2","b2")
data <- data.frame(x1,x2)

x1 x2
a  a1
a  a1 
a  a2
a  a1
a  a2
a  a3
b  b1
b  b1
b  b2 
b  b2
```

I want to find the number of unique values of `x1` corresponding to `x2`

For example `a` has only 3 unique values (`a1,a2` and `a3`) and `b` has 2 values (`b1` and `b2`)

I used `aggregate(x1~.,data,sum)` but it did not work since these are factors, not integers.

Please help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
 aggregate(x2~x1, data, FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))
 #  x1 x2
 #1  a  3
 #2  b  2
```

Or

```
 rowSums(table(unique(data)))
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
     group_by(x1) %>%
     summarise(n=n_distinct(x2))
```

Or another option using `dplyr` suggested by @Eric

```
count(distinct(data), x1)
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, uniqueN(x2) , x1]
```

#### Update

If you need both the `unique` values of 'x2' and the count

```
setDT(data)[, list(n=uniqueN(x2), x2=unique(x2)) , x1]
```

Or only the `unique` values

```
setDT(data)[, list(x2=unique(x2)) , x1]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 unique(data, by=x1) %>% 
                   group_by(x1) %>%
                   mutate(n=n_distinct(x2))
```

only for unique values

```
unique(data, by=x1)
```

Comment: Or `library(dplyr); count(distinct(data), x1)` ;-)

Comment: Hey can i also list the unique values : `a a1 a2 a3`   `b b1 b2`

Comment: @Learner27 Updated with a data.table option.